# Collision Detection between a sprite and an array of sprites

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I'm working on an infinite runner and I need to have collision detection between a single sprite, and any sprite out of a CCArray of sprites. How do you suggest that I do this? Currently this is the method that I call to check for collisions, but it isn't working.

```
bool RunningScene::spritesAreColliding(cocos2d::CCSprite *spr1, cocos2d::CCSprite *spr2)
{
//Take the bounding box of the two sprites that are bounded
CCRect r1 = spr1->boundingBox();
CCRect r2 = spr2->boundingBox();

if (r1.intersectsRect(r2)) { //Check if the bounding boxes are intersecting and return a true/false
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

}

I use it in an if statement, and if it returns true, the if statement works.
I'm not hoping for pixel perfect collision detection, but I'm wondering if that method will work for checking collisions, and I'm wondering how to access any sprite from the CCArray that happens to be colliding with the _runner sprite.

Comment: What is it about it that isn't working? It might be a little more efficient if you had `return r1.intersectsRect(r2);` but the concept looks basically sound.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure  why your code isn't working, because I can't see what you are doing. Suppose that the method returns true. What do you do?

Collision detection is difficult. I suggest you check out the appropriate chapters of this book: [Real Time Collision Detection](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/).

There are two approaches: continuous and discrete.

It looks like you're trying to use discrete collision detection. This is when you react to collisions *after* they happen. You need to find the penetration axis, so that you know in which direction to 'push the boxes apart'. One simple yet slow way to accomplish this is to do a sort of 'binary search' for the moment *just before* they began colliding. Take the objects to their positions before their velocities were applied (start of frame). Now apply half of their velocities. Are they intersecting? If not, apply 0.75 of their velocities, and if yes, apply 0.25 of their velocities. Repeat for a preset number of iterations and until they are no longer intersecting.

You will also have to set their velocities so that they either 'bounce back' or at least stop moving along the axis that they last intersected on.

Discrete collision detection is problematic. The most well known problem is tunneling. This is when objects are moving so fast that they do not intersect. When their velocities are applied, the 'move through one another' and the collision is never caught. For 2D collision detection, I recommend the continuous approach.